# Image adjust on UIImageView like FB cover photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

[image]

**Requirement:**

I want to user register with cover photo. So i want to cover photo like Facebook.

**My Problem:**

2) When I set image on cover photo, it will stretch it self which should not be stretch..

3) User should be able to adjust with scroll or Gesture.

Please help me ..

Comment: Change `UIImageView` property to AspectFit or AspectFill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best Way to achieve it is:

Step 1: Put Your Imageview in One View With Same Frame of ImageView want.

Step 2: Set Image Content Mode & userInteractionEnabled

```
YourImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
YourImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Step 3: Declare Pan Gesture

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture;
```

Step 4: Define PanGesture as well as Assign that YourImageview.

```
self.panGesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureComplete:)];
[YourImageView addGestureRecognizer:self.panGesture];
```

**(Updated)**
Step 5: Add Following Method..

```
-(void)panGestureComplete : (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)parameter{

    if (parameter.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && parameter.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {

        CGPoint point=[parameter locationInView:parameter.view.superview];

        // _ViewContainer is the View in which image lies..

        if ( CGRectContainsPoint(_ViewContainer.bounds, point) ) {
            // Point lies inside the your view Container bounds.
            CGPoint pntTemp=_imgView.center;
            pntTemp.y=point.y;
            parameter.view.center=pntTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

You're Done..
Hope this Helps.. :)

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya can you tell when it's not smooth working?

Comment: When picture move up its fit on imageview but again i want to move down picture its stuck at previous position.

Comment: It's because your Imageview Totally gets Out to its containerview. & so it can not accept the gesture.....

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya Updated My answer with limiting the drag to the bound ... Try it..

Comment: Thanks! Now i can move up and down picture but it is not full picture to view  means i can move up and down only half image not full.

Comment: That's because you want user to adjust image. If full image is visible then no need to adjust right?